# Is this a valid proof to prove that if $a_n$ converges, then $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ converges to $0$? by definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

I saw someone's comment on another website on this proof and they presented this (by definition):

> now, by the definition of a convergent sequence,
>   for all $\epsilon _1 >0$ there is in fact an $n> N_1$ such that it ensures $|a_n - L| < \epsilon _1$, where $L$ is the limit of $a_n$.
>   Now, this means that $a_{n+1}$ is also a convergent sequence so
>   for all $\epsilon _2 > 0$ there is in fact an $n> N_2$ such that it ensures $|a_{n+1} - L| < \epsilon_2$, where $L$ is the limit of $a_{n+1}$.
>   Now consider,
>   $|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ for some $n>N$
>   Now if we were to pick $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then we have our result.

Comment: yes, its valid.

Comment: The relation between $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$ should be clarified.

Comment: @A.Γ. What would the relationship be? I thought that there doesn't *have* to be a relationship, since it must work for all $\epsilon$ anyway?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours Yes, $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, but not $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ that must be small enough **compared to $\epsilon$**. For example, $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by small enough compared to $\epsilon$. it makes me think that you mean that the ratio $\frac{\epsilon_1}{\epsilon}$ approaches zero or something, sorry

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours The last inequality is a relation, for example, $$|a_{n+1} - a_n| = | a_{n+1} -L + L - a_n| \leq |a_{n+1} - L| + |L-a_n|\le\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2\le\epsilon$$ We need to choose $\epsilon_k$ so small to ensure that their sum is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: @A.Γ. strictly less, in fact.

Comment: The shortest proof: convergent $\Rightarrow$ Cauchy $\Rightarrow$ $|a_n-a_m|\le\epsilon$. In particular, for $m=n+1$ too.

Comment: There is no need for multiple epsilon, since the condition $n>N_1$ is valid for both $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find the proof particularly well-structured. While there are many ways to prove such a claim, if one wishes to stick close to the definition this might be a clearer approach:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. For all $n$, we have $|a_{n+1} - a_n| = | a_{n+1} -L + L - a_n| \leq |a_{n+1} - L| + |L-a_n|$, by the triangle inequality. Because the sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $L$ by assumption, there is an $N_1$ such that for all $n > N_1$, we have $|a_n - L| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, and similarly an $N_2$ so that $|a_{n+1} - L| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.
If we pick $N = \max \{N_1, N_2\}$, then for all $n > N$:
$$|a_{n-1} - a_n| < 2 \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$

What I find missing in the given proof is the use of the triangle inequality and what $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ are doing.

Comment: Ah I see, so they basically (possibly) did the triangle inequality in their head, but the proof itself is lacking that step?

Comment: I would say so. At early stages of analysis, it is probably expected to note such things (later on, not so much, but then I wouldn't bother with using the epsilon-delta definition to prove this, either).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is correct. Using the triangular inequality: $|a_{n+1} - a_n| = |a_{n+1} -L + L - a_n| \le |a_{n+1} - L| + |a_n - L| < \epsilon$, therefore when you take the limit you get $a_{n+1} - a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's fine, yet it'd be way easier and shorter if we use arithmetic of limits: since we're given $\;\{a_n\}\;$ converges, there exists $\;L\in \Bbb R\;$ s.t.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L\,.\;\text{ But trivially also}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=L\implies \;\text{by arithmetic of limits,}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L-L=0$$

and we're done.